# The old idler pulley bolt doesn't fit the new one, what can I do?

Tags: bearing, idler, peugeot-406

Since my timing belt idler pulley was making noise, today I decided to replace it with a new one. When I installed the new bearing, I noticed that I can't use the old bolt to tighten it because it requires a shorter bolt. In fact, I run out of threads in the engine block. I have uploaded pictures of the two bearings. Both are OEM. The problem is that the metal one is like a cavity (the plastic one doesn't have any empty space). Is it possible to use a spacer to fill the area? It is impossible to find the original bolt in my area.

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

Fortunately, I found the original bolt (red arrow) and don't need to do anything with the long bolt!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try and turn the idler over? If not, you can put some kind of spacer in there, even if you stack some flat washers. Either that or you've got the wrong idler.

Comment: Is this for the timing belt or serpentine belt?

Comment: Cut that bolt down to length and tap threads on it. Or look in the odds and ends box for a shorter bolt.

Comment: @HandyHowie - For timing belt.

Comment: @Solar Mike - I also thought about cutting the bolt but I'm extremely frightened to do it because I don't want to lose the bolt. As you know, when you cut a bolt, there is a risk of thread damage.

Comment: @Paulster2 - Is is risky to run an idler bearing which is tightened by a spacer?

Comment: The threads will be fine on the bit you cut off. Just put new threads on the remaining shank - a common easy job for a mechanic.

Comment: Examine the old idler pulley. I think it has a removable flanged steel bushing. It may be seized and difficult to remove to fit into the new one without this bushing. If you're lucky, the bushing will come of with little resistance. On the other hand, the new one may be an incorrect replacement part.

Comment: @F Dryer - No, it is not an incorrect part. This engine has been offered with two different bearings (metal and plastic). In fact, the original bearing on the car was a metal one. I replaced it with a plastic one and then again I'm replacing it with a metal one.

Comment: @Solar Mike - Wish mechanics in my area were as talented as the ones in your area! They don't even know how to bleed a cooling system properly let alone putting threads on a bolt shank!

Comment: So as you had the bolt for the original metal one, where is it as that one will fit.

Comment: @Solar Mike - The original idler bearing (which was also a metal one) was replaced by a mechanic about 5 years ago. I don't know what he did with its bolt because he replaced it with a plastic one which had a different bolt. Unfortunately, I didn't have enough skills to replace my timing belt and its bearing back then. So, it was quite easy to fall victim to terrible things they did!

Comment: Well, changing story, last time you said "I replaced it..." should have been "I had it replaced..."

Comment: @Solar Mike - People usually say I replaced this or that even when they have a mechanic does it for them. In fact, I bought the plastic one because the metal one was not available at the market 5 years ago. So, I bought a plastic bearing and gave it to the mechanic.